# Argument out of range exception when using asp-for instead of name in input tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have the following Model Class:

```
public class EmployeeInfo
       {
           public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
           public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
           public string EmailAddress { get; set; } = null!;
           public virtual List<EmergencyInfo> EmergencyInfos { get; set; } = new List<EmergencyInfo>();
       }

public partial class EmergencyInfo
{
    public int EmergencyInfoId { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeInfoId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [Required]
    public string? LastName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

My razor page looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                @if (Model != null && Model.EmergencyInfos != null && Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    var count = Model.EmergencyInfos.Count;
                    @for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label class="control-label">LastName</label>
                                <input asp-for="EmergencyInfos[i].LastName" value="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[i].LastName)? "": @Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[i].LastName)" class="form-control" />/>
                                <span asp-validation-for="EmergencyInfos[i].LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                       </div>  
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                   
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label asp-for="EmergencyInfos[0].LastName" class="control-label">LastName</label>
                             <input asp-for="EmergencyInfos[0].LastName" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="EmergencyInfos[0].LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                   
                }
            </div>
```

With the above Razor View, I get this error:

[image]

If I change

```
  <input asp-for="EmergencyInfos[0].LastName" class="form-control" />
```

to

```
<input name="EmergencyInfos[0].LastName" class="form-control" />
```

then  I dont get any error, but I dont get validation of LastName either that says "Last Name field is required"
As you can see LastName in emergencyInfo is required. I am not sure how to fix this. Below is the exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
lambda_method172(Closure , EmployeeInfo )

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
lambda_method172(Closure , EmployeeInfo )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ExpressionMetadataProvider+<>c__DisplayClass0_0<TModel, TResult>.<FromLambdaExpression>g__modelAccessor|0(object container)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExplorer.get_Model()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExplorer.get_ModelType()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper.GetInputTypeHints(ModelExplorer modelExplorer)+MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper.GetInputType(ModelExplorer modelExplorer, out string inputTypeHint)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper.Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Employee_Create.<ExecuteAsync>b__21_0() in Create.cshtml
+
                                <input asp-for="EmergencyInfos[0].LastName" class="form-control" />
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.GetChildContentAsync(bool useCachedResult, HtmlEncoder encoder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.RenderAtEndOfFormTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Employee_Create.ExecuteAsync() in Create.cshtml
+
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|22_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ...are those classes EF entity classes? If so, then **don't do that**: you should not be using EF entity types as mutable view-models for `<form>` binding in ASP.NET MVC/ASP.NET Core: you need to define separate classes for those (yes, I agree it's painful and annoying having to repeat member definitions multiple times).

Comment: Please paste the text of the exception rather than an image (it helps for copy/pasting, screen readers, and language translation)\

Comment: What is the difference between `EmergencyInfos` and `Model.EmergencyInfos`?

Comment: I pasted the exception above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a bug in the code , both parts if...else are the same

```
@if (Model != null && Model.EmergencyInfos != null && Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList().Count > 0)
{
....
  <input asp-for="EmergencyInfos[i].LastName" value="@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[i].LastName)? "": @Model.EmergencyInfos.ToList()[i].LastName)" class="form-control" />/>
 ...                               
}
else
{
....                   
                    
<input asp-for="EmergencyInfos[0].LastName" class="form-control" />
....                         
}
```

EmergencyInfos[0].LastName is out of range, since EmergencyInfos[0] doesn't exist, the list is empty

IMHO it is a very bad idea to put all the code in the MVC view. You have to make this check in a controller, and if there is not data then to add an empty record to the list and create a special flag in a model